# Regex - delete everything but matching groups (using sublime 3)

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

How can I keep only matching groups and delete the rest of the text?

Using: Sublime 3 - Regex

My pattern is

```
1.5.1 Bla bla bla
text text text
text text text
1.5.2 Bla bla bla
text text text
```

I want to keep only this

```
1.5.1 Bla bla bla
1.5.2 Bla bla bla
```

I can manage to select only the groups, but not everything except them.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/pV9xU6/2

Thank you

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Do you mean you need to match `5.1.`+any digits and then the rest of the line and the next line, and remove all the rest?

Comment: Try `(?s)^(1\.5\.\d+[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)|.` and replace with `$1` (I see your sample input in the question differs from what you have in the demo, you might want to adjust the hardcoded digits at the pattern start)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/cV4iS0/1

Comment: Append `(*SKIP)(*F)|.*\R*` to your regex: `(1[.]5[.]\d+.*\n.*\n)(*SKIP)(*F)|.*\R*` and replace it with nothing.

Comment: You can do it like this: https://regex101.com/r/uS4oK1/3

Comment: @Chathurika Sublime it's a text editor, like notepad++, but it uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Almost that. I want to match 5.1.+any digit, the rest of the line, BUT for all the occurences, deleting the text between those matching groups. At your example, appear the same problem that I still have. It only keep the first matching group, and erase the rest of the text.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @Tromens: No, because you test at regex101 and you did not enable the `m` option that is ON by default in SublimeText. Again, see https://regex101.com/r/cV4iS0/1. All 3 solutions in these comments above work.

Comment: @revo That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm.. I didn't know that this option was on by default at sublime. It works too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, it can be done in several ways:

```
Find: (?s)^(1\.5\.\d+[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)|.        /gm
Replace: $1
```

or

```
Find (general way): (*SKIP)(*F)|.*\R*
Find: (1[.]5[.]\d+.*\n.*\n)(*SKIP)(*F)|.*\R*
Replace: nothing
```

or

```
Find: (^1\.5\.\d+.*\n.*\n)\K(?>.*\R)*?(?=(?1)|.*\z)     /gm
Replace: nothing
```

Thanks for all your help.